# Oracle start Sequence from 1

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I am maintaining a database using Oracle 10g and I would like to have a sequence that starts from 1 and increments by 1 with each additional row.

I have created the following statement in order to achieve this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE PATIENTS_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMINVALUE NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
```

However, upon inserting the first entry into the table with value (PATIENTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL), the count starts at 2 instead of 1. If I modify my sequence to start with 0, then I get an error that the start with value cannot be less than the minvalue. Can anyone help troubleshoot how to get my count to start properly from 1?

Comment: I can't repro.  I get an initial value of `1` when I create this sequence.

Comment: Very strange, no matter what I do it starts with an initial value of `2`. I went with horse's suggestion. Thanks for trying to reproduce the error though.

Comment: Maybe you have a "before insert" trigger on the table that is getting the next value from the sequence and using that as the PK's value?  In other words, you may be accidentally getting the nextval twice.

Comment: I'm on 11g if that makes any difference.

Comment: I definitely don't have any user-defined "before insert" triggers. I've tried this with a simple table, `CREATE TABLE PATIENTS(ID INT CONSTRAINT PATIENTS_KEY PRIMARY KEY);`.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I'm on 10g and I'm not sure if that makes a difference either.

Comment: Basically I just ran `CREATE SEQUENCE PATIENTS_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMINVALUE NOCACHE NOCYCLE;` and then I ran `select PATIENTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual;` and I get `1`.

Comment: I did an `INSERT INTO PATIENTS(PATIENTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL)` and the first row value was equal to 2. Should I be doing this in a different manner?

Comment: @raphnguyen - No, they should be the same.  When I create the table and try the INSERT, I start with `1`.  Must be a `10g` behavior.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to any `10g` databases to try it out.  I'm curious what happens if you run `select PATIENTS_SEQ.CURRVAL from dual;` right after you create the sequence.

Comment: FWIW, I just ran this on a 10.2.0.5.0 instance and got 1 as the id.  Here's my script: `CREATE SEQUENCE PATIENTS_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMINVALUE NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
CREATE TABLE PATIENTS(ID INT CONSTRAINT PATIENTS_KEY PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO PATIENTS(id) values (PATIENTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL);
SELECT * FROM PATIENTS;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply set the minvalue to 0 as well:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE PATIENTS_SEQ 
  START WITH 0 
  INCREMENT BY 1 
  MINVALUE 0 
  NOCACHE 
  NOCYCLE;
```

Comment: Why MINVALUE 0?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I want to know the reason why it works.