SQL Oracle sequence not starting at 1?
Created a patient table with sequence:
CREATE SEQUENCE Pt_ID_SEQ
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
NOMAXVALUE
MINVALUE 1
NOCACHE;
After inserting 10 rows into the patient table, I did select* from patient to see the results.
The first Pt_ID is 31! How can I fix this so the first patient inserted is patient 1?
Have tried dropping all sequences, dropping all tables, and restarting SQL. Everytime I try and populate the patient table the starting number keeps getting bigger by the 10's (now patient 1 has a pt_ID of 41).

Not an answer, but why do you need the sequence to begin at 1, assuming each new value would be unique and generally increasing?

My professor requires this in the project description!

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438861/oracle-start-sequence-from-1

If there is no really good and urgent reason (that someone just told you to do so is no reason at all), get rid of those obsolete sequences. Oracle is simply obsolete and slow in some cases (see also that ugly need to use a dual table for so many years before now, you can finally skip it). That's why they used sequences for such long time. It's far simpler to rather use identities and they will start by 1. Just write your_column_name number(max_length) generated always as identity (start with 1 increment by 1) and you are done.
